# Invalidation from Mutations in React Query

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-query

I am uploading an image in the backend using react-query useMutation. Everything is working correctly, but onSuccess in useMutation when invalidateQueries is called it's inValidating the useQuery before the POST request gets executed successfully on the backend. So I have to refresh the page for new images.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuMZu.png)

```
  const { data: usermedia,} = useQuery(["usermedia"],() => {
    return getInfo("http://127.0.0.1:8000/usermedia/").then((t) => t.json());}, 
  );
```

```
  const mutation = useMutation(
    (body) => postMedia("http://127.0.0.1:8000/usermedia/", body),
    { 
      onSuccess:(data,) => {
         console.log("Got response from backend successfull", data); 
         client.invalidateQueries("usermedia")
    
      },
      onError(error) {
         console.log("Got error from backend", error);},
    }
  );
```

I am was expecting to InValidate query when the POST got completed in the backend OR after inValidating useQuery it got triggered after 1 sec.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try and return the invalidatequeries call as demonstrated here https://tkdodo.eu/blog/mastering-mutations-in-react-query

```
{
  //  will wait for query invalidation to finish
  onSuccess: () => {
    return queryClient.invalidateQueries(['posts', id, 'comments'])
  }
}
{
  //  fire and forget - will not wait
  onSuccess: () => {
    queryClient.invalidateQueries(['posts', id, 'comments'])
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you think that "try and return the invalidatequeries call" is the solution you mean to provide? Note that the linked content is not considered part of the answer. And your answer seems very brief and short on details if judged only by what you provide here....

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).